# Apply filter with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following line of code:

```
Me.Filter = "[SN] = '" & Me!AcftSN.Value & "'" & " and [Formdate] between "/
 & Me!startdate.Value & " and " & Me!enddate.Value
```

which returns the following string:

"[SN] = '4A2' and [Formdate] between 1/2/2005 and 3/10/2016"

[SN] is text and [Formdate] is date

When run, I receive a report with no records. This worked properly with only the first criteria (SN=4A2), so I think there is an issue with the 'and' or with the date values being read incorrectly.  Can someone help with syntax?

Comment: What type is `me`? Have you tried setting the filter manually and did it work?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do format the date values as string expressions:

```
Me.Filter = "[SN] = '" & Me!AcftSN.Value & "'" & " and [Formdate] between #" & Format(Me!startdate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# and #" & Format(Me!enddate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```